# Android Studio failed to build App Engine module

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I tried to generate app engine backend for android app module in Android Studio. First I had encountered the Maven nonexistence problem, which was solved later on. Then another problem appeared.

[image]

---

Below is the error log generated:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project AndroidBackend-AppEngine: Compilation failure
>
> [ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\arifsamin.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\orm\datanucleus-appengine\2.1.2\datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar; error in opening zip file

Do I have to download a new repo due to this? If I have to how to do so? Android Studio is very alien to me.

Comment: how do you exactly invoke build? this error comes from maven-compiler-plugin. Android Studio uses Gradle for build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have fresh install of Android Studio 0.2.+. Upgrade from pre 0.2 doesn't work as google included extra maven repo to serve support libraries.

**Edit:**

path in the log is correct, just stackoverflow plays silly and hides \ before .

Comment: yep, exactly. I was migrating from eclipse recently and unaware of this notice. problem solved.